# Hello. On requesting via ChainLink playground source.js it returns a value but in the code I get Error:returned value not an ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array

Tags: chainlink, constellation

This is the code

```
const city = args[0];
const state = args[1];
const country = args[2];



    // Execute the API request (Promise)
    const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=${city}&state=${state}&country=${country}&key=${secrets.apiKey}`,
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(apiResponse));
    // Check if the response contains valid data
if (apiResponse.data && apiResponse.data.data && apiResponse.data.data.current && apiResponse.data.data.current.pollution) {
    // Extract the aqius value
    const aqius = apiResponse.data.data.current.pollution.aqius || 0;
    console.log(aqius);

    return Functions.encodeString(JSON.stringify(aqius));
} else {
    console.error('Invalid or missing data in the API response.');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  This was posted in the Constellation Hackathon Discord as an answer:

> To address the “returned value not an ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array” error, ensure that the response and error parameters in your fulfillRequest function are consistently typed as bytes or bytes32. This error typically arises from a data type mismatch during function communication. Verify that your encoding and decoding processes align with Chainlink expectations, and confirm that the response from fulfillRequest is properly converted to bytes."

Check to make sure your fulfillRequest() function has the data types entered correctly.  It should look like below as referenced [here](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/simple-computation).

```
function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    )
```

The issue for me was I entered my JavaScript source code as shown in an outdated demonstration.  A previous demo had you set source like:

```
string source = "line 1;"
    "line 2;"
    "line 3;"
    "line 4;";
```

When I changed it to one giant line of code it resolved my error:

```
string source = "line 1;line 2;line 3;line 4";
```

I'm not certain why the first method failed and the second worked but I suspect the DON nodes were only performing my first line of code and never getting to the return statement of my JavaScript.